# List importation from .txt

Tags: python, string, list

I have a problem with a cryptography program I'm writing.

I must import a crypted text from a .txt file and decipher it. My function that takes care of the deciphering is ok, but it needs a *list of numbers* in order to do so.
The problem is, as I import that previously mentioned *list of numbers* from a .txt, it is read as a string, not a list of numbers.

To clarify : I import a string that looks like "1243, 56, 29, 987, 76,... 34" and I need a list [1243, 56, 29, 987, 76,... 34].

Edit : added the code

```
objet3 = open("chiffre1.txt", "r")
code = objet3.read()
décodé = déchiffrer(code,dictio)
```

Comment: OK, so what have you tried and what is the problem with it?

Comment: use `split(",")` and `open(filename, 'r')`

Comment: Yes I tried it, that's how I saw it was considered as a string.

Comment: Ian : I must write split(",") then open(filename, 'r') on two lines, or one ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
[int(item) for item in string.split(",")]
```

will do the job for you.

Gotta love iterators and lists in Python, so beautiful.

Comment: Item must be replaced by what here ? Sorry for dumb question I'm really a newbie in code ^^'

Comment: No problem (though this community is usually not up for 'tutorial stuff') "item" does not need to be replaced at all. Just replace "string" with the name of your variable containing the numbers as a string. Basically as others suggested String.split splits it into parts. That gives us a list containing the parts. Then we can iterate through this list by "dosomething for everyitem in thislist" where dosomething is our int-casting and item the current part of the string. Take a look at regular expressions and also try to do this whole thing in Python-Idle for a deeper understanding.

Comment: Thanks, it worked ! And I understood why.

Answer (score 0):

Use split():

```
list = '1243, 56, 29, 987, 76'
new_array = list.split(',')

print new_array
```

Comment: I must do it for any cases, with variables. Will still work ?